# How to draw a rectangle containing an object in Android (Java, OpenCV)

Tags: java, android, opencv

Basically, I want to achieve [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcswZLwhTUI), and so far, I've written the following Java code...

```
    // Display the camera frame
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        // The object's width and height are set to 0
        objectWidth = objectHeight = 0;

        // frame is captured as a coloured image
        frame = inputFrame.rgba();

        /** Since the Canny algorithm only works on greyscale images and the captured image is
         *  coloured, we transform the captured cam image into a greyscale one
         */
        Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, grey, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        // Calculating borders of image using the Canny algorithm
        Imgproc.Canny(grey, canny, 180, 210);

        /** To avoid background noise (given by the camera) that makes the system too sensitive
         *  small variations, the image is blurred to a small extent. Blurring is one of the
         *  required steps before any image transformation because this eliminates small details
         *  that are of no use. Blur is a low-pass filter.
         */
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(canny, canny, new Size(5, 5), 5);

        // Calculate the contours
        Imgproc.findContours(canny, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        /** The contours come in different sequences
         *  1 sequence for each connected component.
         *  Taking the assumption only 1 object is in view, if we have more than 1 connected
         *  component, this'll be considered part of the details of the object.
         *
         *  For this, we put all contours together in a single sequence
         *  If there is at least 1 contour, I can continue processing
         */
        for (MatOfPoint mat : contours) {
            // Retrieve and store all contours in one giant map
            mat.copyTo(allContours);
        }

        MatOfPoint2f allCon = new MatOfPoint2f(allContours.toArray());

        // Calculating the minimal rectangle to contain the contours
        RotatedRect box = Imgproc.minAreaRect(allCon);

        // Getting the vertices of the rectangle
        Point[] vertices = initialiseWithDefaultPointInstances(4);
        box.points(vertices);

        // Now the vertices are in possession, temporal smoothing can be performed.
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                // Smooth coordinate x of the vertex
                vertices[i].x = alpha * lastVertices[i].x + (1.0 - alpha) * vertices[i].x;
                // Smooth coordinate y of the vertex
                vertices[i].y = alpha * lastVertices[i].y + (1.0 - alpha) * vertices[i].y;
                // Assign the present smoothed values as lastVertices for the next smooth
                lastVertices[i] = vertices[i];
            }

        /** With the vertices, the object size is calculated.
         *  The object size is calculated through pythagoras theorm. In addition, it gives
         *  the distance between 2 points in a bi-dimensional space.
         *
         *  For a rectangle, considering any vertex V, its two sizes (width and height) can
         *  be calculated by calculating the distance of V from the previous vertex and
         *  calculating the distance of V from the next vertex. This is the reason why I
         *  calculate the distance between vertici[0]/vertici[3] and vertici[0]/vertici[1]
         */
        objectWidth = (int) (conversionFactor * Math.sqrt((vertices[0].x - vertices[3].x) * (vertices[0].x - vertices[3].x) + (vertices[0].y - vertices[3].y) * (vertices[0].y - vertices[3].y)));
        objectHeight = (int) (conversionFactor * Math.sqrt((vertices[0].x - vertices[1].x) * (vertices[0].x - vertices[1].x) + (vertices[0].y - vertices[1].y) * (vertices[0].y - vertices[1].y)));

        /** Draw the rectangle containing the contours. The line method draws a line from 1
         *  point to the next, and accepts only integer coordinates; for this reason, 2
         *  temporary Points have been created and why I used Math.round method.
         */
        Point pt1 = new Point();
        Point pt2 = new Point();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            pt1.x = Math.round(vertices[i].x);
            pt1.y = Math.round(vertices[i].y);
            pt2.x = Math.round(vertices[(i + 1) % 4].x);
            pt2.y = Math.round(vertices[(i + 1) % 4].y);
            Imgproc.line(frame, pt1, pt2, red, 3);
        }

        //If the width and height are non-zero, then print the object size on-screen
        if (objectWidth != 0 && objectHeight != 0) {
            String text;
            text = String.format("%d x %d", objectWidth, objectHeight);
            widthValue.setText(text);
        }


        // This function must return
        return frame;
    }

    // Initialising an array of points
    public static Point[] initialiseWithDefaultPointInstances(int length) {
        Point[] array = new Point[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = new Point();
        }
        return array;
    }
```

What I want to achieve is drawing a rectangle on-screen that contains the object's contours (edges). If anyone knows the answer to my question, please feel free to comment below, as I have been stuck on this for a couple of hours

Comment: I think one issues is, that you are throwing all contours into one Mat. If you have multiple objects, you will also have multiple boxes. This code draws all the contours, so the drawing function looks good. for(MatOfPoint contour : contours){
            Point[] points = contour.toArray();
            for(int i=0; i < points.length - 1; i++){
                Imgproc.line(frame, points[i], points[i + 1 % points.length], new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 3);
            }
        }

Comment: Funny enough, I'm actually trying to store all contours into 1 Mat because I want to draw a rectangle containing 1 object, which will allow me to take and convert the pixel width and height of the rectangle into mm. Basically, I want to measure 1 object at a time.

Comment: This code works for me to draw the lines https://gist.github.com/sladomic/6c792e4d059cd3b3ab9676a9128d825b but the code is not optimized and the temporal smoothing is missing. If you want to restrict to only one object, why don't you just use contours.get(0) and if there are more than 1 objects you just output an error message?

Comment: I took your code and just changed everything to lists and additional loops. But as mentioned, this might not be efficient. It's better to calculate directly with OpenCV (e.g. Core.add(), Core.subtract()) to get a better performance. But in my quick test it was fast enough for real-time usage.

Comment: Thank you so much man! Works like a dream! :D

Comment: yeah, I just placed it there because I didn't want to post it as a final answer here yet.

Comment: Actually, as you're the one who solved the issue, it's only fair that you make the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code referenced in the comment [How to draw a rectangle containing an object in Android (Java, OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235495/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-containing-an-object-in-android-java-opencv?noredirect=1#comment83463504_48235495)

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // The object's width and height are set to 0
    List<Integer> objectWidth = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> objectHeight = new ArrayList<>();

    // frame is captured as a coloured image
    Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Mat canny = new Mat();
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();

    /** Since the Canny algorithm only works on greyscale images and the captured image is
     *  coloured, we transform the captured cam image into a greyscale one
     */
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    // Calculating borders of image using the Canny algorithm
    Imgproc.Canny(gray, canny, 180, 210);

    /** To avoid background noise (given by the camera) that makes the system too sensitive
     *  small variations, the image is blurred to a small extent. Blurring is one of the
     *  required steps before any image transformation because this eliminates small details
     *  that are of no use. Blur is a low-pass filter.
     */
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(canny, canny, new Size(5, 5), 5);

    // Calculate the contours
    Imgproc.findContours(canny, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    /** The contours come in different sequences
     *  1 sequence for each connected component.
     *  Taking the assumption only 1 object is in view, if we have more than 1 connected
     *  component, this'll be considered part of the details of the object.
     *
     *  For this, we put all contours together in a single sequence
     *  If there is at least 1 contour, I can continue processing
     */

    if(contours.size() > 0){
        // Calculating the minimal rectangle to contain the contours
        List<RotatedRect> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(MatOfPoint contour : contours){
            RotatedRect box = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray()));
            boxes.add(box);
        }

        // Getting the vertices of the rectangle

        List<Point[]> vertices = initialiseWithDefaultPointInstances(boxes.size(), 4);
        for(int i=0; i<boxes.size(); i++){
            boxes.get(i).points(vertices.get(i));
        }

        /*
        double alpha = 0.5;
        // Now the vertices are in possession, temporal smoothing can be performed.
            for(int i = 0; i<vertices.size(); i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    // Smooth coordinate x of the vertex
                    vertices.get(i)[j].x = alpha * lastVertices.get(i)[j].x + (1.0 - alpha) * vertices.get(i)[j].x;
                    // Smooth coordinate y of the vertex
                    vertices.get(i)[j].y = alpha * lastVertices.get(i)[j].y + (1.0 - alpha) * vertices.get(i)[j].y;
                    // Assign the present smoothed values as lastVertices for the next smooth
                    lastVertices.get(i)[j] = vertices.get(i)[j];
                }
        }*/

        /** With the vertices, the object size is calculated.
         *  The object size is calculated through pythagoras theorm. In addition, it gives
         *  the distance between 2 points in a bi-dimensional space.
         *
         *  For a rectangle, considering any vertex V, its two sizes (width and height) can
         *  be calculated by calculating the distance of V from the previous vertex and
         *  calculating the distance of V from the next vertex. This is the reason why I
         *  calculate the distance between vertici[0]/vertici[3] and vertici[0]/vertici[1]
         */
        double conversionFactor = 1.0;
        for(Point[] points : vertices){
            int width = (int) (conversionFactor * Math.sqrt((points[0].x - points[3].x) * (points[0].x - points[3].x) + (points[0].y - points[3].y) * (points[0].y - points[3].y)));
            int height = (int) (conversionFactor * Math.sqrt((points[0].x - points[1].x) * (points[0].x - points[1].x) + (points[0].y - points[1].y) * (points[0].y - points[1].y)));
            objectWidth.add(width);
            objectHeight.add(height);
        }



        /** Draw the rectangle containing the contours. The line method draws a line from 1
         *  point to the next, and accepts only integer coordinates; for this reason, 2
         *  temporary Points have been created and why I used Math.round method.
         */
        Scalar red = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
        for (int i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++){
            Point pt1 = new Point();
            Point pt2 = new Point();
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                pt1.x = Math.round(vertices.get(i)[j].x);
                pt1.y = Math.round(vertices.get(i)[j].y);
                pt2.x = Math.round(vertices.get(i)[(j + 1) % 4].x);
                pt2.y = Math.round(vertices.get(i)[(j + 1) % 4].y);
                Imgproc.line(frame, pt1, pt2, red, 3);
            }
            if (objectWidth.get(i) != 0 && objectHeight.get(i) != 0){
                Imgproc.putText(frame, "width: " + objectWidth + ", height: " + objectHeight, new Point(Math.round(vertices.get(i)[1].x), Math.round(vertices.get(i)[1].y)), 1, 1, red);
            }
        }

    }


    // This function must return
    return frame;
}

// Initialising an array of points
public static List<Point[]> initialiseWithDefaultPointInstances(int n_Contours, int n_Points) {
    List<Point[]> pointsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n_Contours; i++){
        Point[] array = new Point[n_Points];
        for (int j = 0; j < n_Points; j++) {
            array[j] = new Point();
        }
        pointsList.add(array);
    }
    return pointsList;
}
```

Comment: How do I specific the object to detect ?